# mongodb is not updated on .put angular function, no errors shown

Tags: html, node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I can't seem to know what is wrong with this code, it shows on the screen the right answer but when I reload the screen or check the database the values are not shown.

**EVENTS.component.html**

```
<div align="center">
  event list for check
  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
      <th> student code </th>
      <th> event code </th>
      <th> participation code </th>
      <th> event link </th>
      <th> verification </th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let e of events">
      <td>{{e.cod_s}}</td>
      <td>{{e.cod_a}}</td>
      <td>{{e.cod_p}}</td>
      <td>{{e.link_e}}</td>
      <td bold>{{e.ver}}</td>
      <td><button (click)="rejectEvent(e._id)" type="submit">rejeitar</button></td>
      <td><button (click)="approveEvent(e._id)" type="submit">aprovar</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**EVENTS.js - put function**

```
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Evento.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function(err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

**EVENTS.component.ts**

```
export class AprovacaoEventosComponent implements OnInit {

  events: any;
  id = 0
  verifica = false;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/EVENTS").subscribe(data => {
      this.eventos = dados;
    })
  }

  rejectEvent(id) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.eventos.length; i++) {
      if (this.eventos[i]['_id'] == id) {
        var index = i;
      }
    }
    this.events[index]['verifica'] = false
    this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/EVENTS/' + id, this.events).subscribe(answer => {
      this.router.navigate(['/EVENT-APPROVAL'])
      console.log('rejected!')
    }, (erro) => {
      console.log("error")
    })
  }

  approveEvent(id) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.eventos.length; i++) {
      if (this.events[i]['_id'] == id) {
        var index = i;
      }
    }
    this.eventos[index]['verifica'] = true
    this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/EVENTS/' + id, this.events).subscribe(resposta => {
      this.router.navigate(['/EVENT-APPROVAL'])
      console.log('approved!')
    }, (erro) => {
      console.log("error")
    })
  }
}
```

I can't find what's wrong in the code because no errors are shown or anything, and it even updates the right events on the right areas but it just don't saves or updates anything on the Mongo DB database.
What to do?

Comment: Check the network tab for the outgoing `PUT` request. See if you're sending the correct PUT Payload. Also, try testing this API out using Postman to see if there's an issue with the API and not with your Front-end.

Comment: id does work on postman the put request... so i dont really know what is going on

Comment: and he is not changing the object sent for some reason